# RemotePlayer vs Media

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast

I'm building a Google Cast integration for a music app in Chrome.

What is the difference between `cast.framework.RemotePlayer` and `chrome.cast.media.Media`?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate#media_control) uses `cast.framework.RemotePlayer` and `cast.framework.RemotePlayerController`, but they don't have functions for managing the queue, while `chrome.cast.media.Media` does.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the `cast.framework` namespace is used for a high-level API built on top of the `chrome.cast` namespace, which is a low-level API.

It doesn't matter whether you use `cast.framework.RemotePlayer` or `chrome.cast.media.Media`, both of them will work, but `Media` has more functions and callbacks.

In my experience, `Media` is easier to work with than `RemotePlayer`, so I don't really get why they created the `RemotePlayer` class.